# "Flight Animation" in d3.js v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geolocation

Im currently trying to wrap my head around connecting points around the map and animating them like - HERE:

> http://www.tnoda.com/flightanimation

I want the points to connect using information in my CSV File:
Specifically 'where' field which will tell us is the place a destination or an origin of the flight:

```
code,city,country,lat,lon,where
ZNZ,ZANZIBAR,TANZANIA,-6.13,39.31,dest
TYO,TOKYO,JAPAN,35.68,139.76,dest
AKL,AUCKLAND,NEW ZEALAND,-36.85,174.78,orgin
BKK,BANGKOK,THAILAND,13.75,100.48,orgin
DEL,DELHI,INDIA,29.01,77.38,orgin
SIN,SINGAPORE,SINGAPOR,1.36,103.75,orgin
BSB,BRASILIA,BRAZIL,-15.67,-47.43,orgin
RIO,RIO DE JANEIRO,BRAZIL,-22.90,-43.24,orgin
YTO,TORONTO,CANADA,43.64,-79.40,orgin
IPC,EASTER ISLAND,CHILE,-27.11,-109.36,orgin
SEA,SEATTLE,USA,47.61,-122.33,orgin
```

(I know i spelled origin wrong its intentionally like that)

Now this is my HTML Code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
path {
        stroke: limegreen;
        stroke-width: 0.25px;
        fill: black;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
    body {
        background-color:darkgrey;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
.packet {
        max-height:  height: 50px;
        max-width: 50px;
        fill: limegreen;

    }
</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/3F7B1EB8-32BF-7449-968C-CB1318D27635/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/53672D8131BC-C869-9447-FB23-8BE1B7F3/abn/main.css"/><script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
    
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()// Creating our projection for our map


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")//Append svg to body
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()//create a path for the projection
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g"); //create an empty space to append

var packet = svg.append("path")
    .attr("width","50px")
    .attr("d", "M612.074,132.141v-2.38c0-8.849-4.016-19.26-11.229-26.473l-0.818-0.818c0,0-0.818,0-0.818-0.818   c-1.636-1.636-3.198-2.38-4.833-4.016c-0.818,0-0.818-0.818-1.636-0.818c-1.636-0.818-4.016-1.636-5.652-2.38   c-0.818,0-0.818-0.818-1.636-0.818c-2.38-0.818-4.833-1.636-7.213-1.636c-0.818,0-0.818,0-1.636,0c-2.38,0-5.651-0.818-8.849-0.818   H43.427c-3.198,0-6.395,0-9.667,0.818c-0.818,0-1.636,0-2.38,0.818c-2.38,0.818-4.834,0.818-6.395,1.636   c-0.818,0-0.818,0.818-1.636,0.818c-1.636,0.818-4.016,1.636-5.652,2.38l-0.818,0.818c-1.636,0.818-3.198,2.38-4.834,3.198   c-0.818,0.818-1.636,1.636-2.38,2.38C4.016,110.428,0.818,117.715,0,125.746c0,0.818,0,0.818,0,1.636v357.384   c0,0.818,0,0.818,0,1.636c1.636,11.229,7.213,20.896,15.244,26.473c7.213,4.833,16.062,8.031,26.473,8.031H569.39c0,0,0,0,0.818,0   l0,0c2.38,0,5.651,0,8.031-0.818c0.818,0,0.818,0,1.636,0c2.38-0.818,4.834-0.818,6.395-1.636h0.818   c17.698-6.395,24.911-21.714,24.911-36.14v-2.38v-0.818v-0.818V134.521c0-0.818,0-0.818,0-1.636   C612.074,132.959,612.074,132.959,612.074,132.141z M560.69,120.913l-252.98,246.51l-57.854-56.218l0,0L51.459,120.838H560.69   V120.913z M29.819,475.099V140.991l187.095,179.882L29.819,475.099z M299.679,491.905H56.292l182.336-149.393l58.597,57.036   c2.38,2.38,4.834,3.198,7.213,4.016h0.818c0.818,0,0.818,0,1.636,0l0,0c0.818,0,1.636,0,1.636,0h0.818   c2.38-0.818,5.651-1.636,7.213-4.016l55.4-53.838l183.079,146.196H299.679z M582.329,475.843L394.417,324.07L582.329,140.99   V475.843z");
    
    var route = svg.append("path");
    
// load and display the World
d3.json("world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) {//Load in the world map ( LOW RES)
    g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
          .geometries)
    .enter()
      .append("path")//append path
      .attr("d", path)//path is d3.geo.path which is the projection
    
    //Loading the countries inside the world load display function to speed up the loading on local server and faster or client
    //Loading the countries here also prevents the dots to be under the map instead on top of it!
    d3.csv("countries.csv", function(error, data) {
        g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
                })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];})
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", "red");
        //Writing out the Cities name
        g.selectAll("text")
            .attr("class","names")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("text") // append text
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
                })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
                })
            .attr("dy", -7) // set y position of bottom of text
            .style("fill", "limegreen") // fill the text with the colour black
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle") // set anchor y justification
            .text(function(d) {return d.city;}); // define the text to display
        
        //Test
        route.selectAll("path")
               .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: 
                      [
                          function(d) {
                              if (d.where === origin){
                                return projection(d.lat,d.lon)
                              }},
                        function(d) {
                            if (d.where === dest){
                                return projection(d.lat,d.lon)
                              }}
                      ]
                      })
               .attr("class", "route")
               .attr("d", path);
            });
    
    //Animating path
    
    // Map Zooimng
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("path")
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
});
svg.call(zoom)
});
    
function transition(packet, route) {
  var l = route.node().getTotalLength();
  packet.transition()
       .duration(5000)
       .attrTween("transform", delta(route.node()));
}
  
function delta(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(i) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    }
  }
}
transition(packet, route);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also if anyone can tell me why is my SVG element not resizing that would be great but i'd say i will be able to figure it out.

If someone can explain to me why is the code not working - point out my mistake in my logic and correct me it would be really helpful.
I'm doing this because Data Visualisation has conquered my interest now.

Cheers!

Also hope my comments can be helpful for people that might have had the same problem and are trying to wrap their head around the code!

Comment: Could you expand on "not working"? What happens when you load your HTML page? (You can look in the web developer console of your browser to see any errors.)

Comment: @LondonRob First -the svg that i'm drawing "letterbox" is taking up my whole view.

Second - the routes are not being displayed at all for some reason the packet is not going from its destination to its origin.